# How to Create Circle on corner of line in css

Tags: css

```css
.line-8 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  left: 240px;
  top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

How to make look like this

[image]

Comment: Please complete your code with at least some html

Answer (score 2):

**Try This:**

```css
.line-8 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: orange;
  position:relative;
  left: 240px;
  top: 15px;
  margin-bottom:35px;
}

.line-8:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="line-8"></div>
```